# Querying normalized database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, normalization

I made 8 tables related DB. How to query it (like select * from dbo.1 where date between x and y, but date is in other table, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a JOIN between the two tables.